# Android Studio - Getting preferences specifically for an account

Tags: android, authentication, save, settings

I am creating an app in which the user can register an account an proceed to log in with that account. now, when logged in, you have a few options ranging from some editText that you can fill in, a checkbox and a seekbar.

however, this is where it gets a bit too complicated for me. When I change these things, they will save. but they will save for the app in general. 
What I want is these preferences (ergo, the checkbox, edittext and seekbar) to save specifically for the users account. right now, it doesn't matter on what account you are, they will all have the same text on the edittext, the same progress on the seekbar, and the checkbox will be the same as well.

So basically, I want account specific preferences. But I have no idea how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the code for the user settings. it's a tabhost that uses multiple little things like buttons and edittextst. right now I am only using sharedpreferences to save the changes done to the edittext, checkbox and button. the picture does not save yet (something else I am trying to fix).

public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
CheckBox notificationsCheckbox;
private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;

TextView username;
TextView phone;
TextView address;
ImageView accountImage;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
public static final String Street = "addressKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.settingsTabhost);
    setTitle("Settings");

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("General Settings");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.firstTab);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("General Settings");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Account Settings");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.secondTab);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Account Settings");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    accountImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPicture);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name))
    {
        username.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));

    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Phone))
    {
        phone.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Phone, ""));

    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Street))
    {
        address.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Street, ""));

    }

    Button imageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pictureButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

    Button bluetoothSettingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetoothBtn);

    bluetoothSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent (SettingsActivity.this, DeviceScanActivity.class));
        }
    });

    volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadSavedSlider();
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            saveSlidePreferences();



        }
    });
    seekbarVolume();

    notificationsCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.notifCheckbox);
    notificationsCheckbox.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadSavedCheckbox();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPicture);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
}

public void run(View view){
    String n  = username.getText().toString();
    String ph  = phone.getText().toString();
    String s  = address.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(Name, n);
    editor.putString(Phone, ph);
    editor.putString(Street, s);

    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadSavedCheckbox() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);



    if (checkBoxValue) {
        notificationsCheckbox.setChecked(true);

    }
    else {
        notificationsCheckbox.setChecked(false);

    }
}

private void loadSavedSlider() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int mProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt("mMySeekBarProgress", 0);
    volumeSeekbar.setProgress(mProgress);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);

    editor.commit();

}

private void seekbarVolume() {
    try {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void saveSlidePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    int mProgress = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
    editor.putInt("mMySeekBarProgress", mProgress).commit();


    editor.commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// here we tell the app to simply save the preferences of the notifications checkbox.
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", notificationsCheckbox.isChecked());

    if (notificationsCheckbox.isChecked()){

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle("Findr");
        builder.setContentText("Notifications Activated");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(8, notification);
    }
    else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle("Findr");
        builder.setContentText("Notifications Deactivated");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(8, notification);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You could just append the username to the key that you use to save and retrieve each preference.

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you for your answer. however, I am not sure how I could do this. do you have any kind similar example?

Comment: It was just an idea I had, I haven't see examples.  Can you post the code where you currently save and retrieve the preferences?

Comment: @DanielNugent there you go, I hope it's not too overwhelming. It makes use of a tabhost to separate ''general settings'' from the ''account settings''. Inside the general settings there is a button to access a bluetooth activity, a checkbox for notifications and a seekbar that does nothing yet. As for the account options: it contains 3 edittextst which are the username, phone and adress. it also contains a clickable button that changes the displayed picture above the button to whatever you selected from the gallery. 
my intentions are to make these options exclusive to each account.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea of how you could achieve your desired result.

First, create an instance variable to store the current username:

```
String uName;
```

I believe you would set it here:

```
public void run(View view){
    String n  = username.getText().toString();
    uName = n;
    //.......
```

Then, whenever you set or retrieve preferences, append `uName` to the key.  This would make it so that the preferences used would be unique to each user.

Examples:

```
public void run(View view){
    String n  = username.getText().toString();
    uName = n; //added
    String ph  = phone.getText().toString();
    String s  = address.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(uName + Name, n); //modified
    editor.putString(uName + Phone, ph); //modified
    editor.putString(uName + Street, s); //modified

    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadSavedCheckbox() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(uName + "CheckBox_Value", false); //modified

    if (checkBoxValue) {
        notificationsCheckbox.setChecked(true);

    }
    else {
        notificationsCheckbox.setChecked(false);

    }
}

private void loadSavedSlider() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int mProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(uName + "mMySeekBarProgress", 0); //modified
    volumeSeekbar.setProgress(mProgress);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(uName + key, value); //modified

    editor.commit();

}
```

And here:

```
    private void saveSlidePreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        int mProgress = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
        editor.putInt(uName + "mMySeekBarProgress", mProgress).commit(); //modified


        editor.commit();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so far, I do think I am getting close but it's not working exactly yet. What I should have mentioned is that the user logs in using their email, not username. so right now I am getting no results with the provided code. the email of the user is typed in an editText and then the user also types in their password. when they log in, there needs to be some kind of code that passes the inputted email from the loginActivity, to the mainActivity and then to the settingsActivity (because when you go in you first enter the main activity screen.